# MAMP: How to change UI language?

Tags: mamp

I am a German user, but I prefer English UI. I've found no setting for the language in MAMP. I can change the URL manually to `?language=English`, but that is lame. How to change the language?

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because my preference settings have german on the preferred language list. So I just change my language preference on my mac:

1. System Preferences from the Apple menu.
2. Click Language & Region.
3. Remove German from the list
4. Add english and Drag it to the second or first position of the Preferred languages list.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed the resource directory `de` to `de-off`. MAMP control panel started in English, but the web page + tools were still in German. I patched `MAMP\bin\mamp\php\functions.php` to fix the $language:

```
$language = 'English';
```

Crude but works. Setting would be better.

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same problem. I set the language to English during installation and the UI is appropriately in English, but when I click on "Open WebStart page", the URL in the browser is http://localhost/MAMP/index.php?language=German.

I tried your method renaming the directory de to de-off and going to MAMP\bin\mamp\php\functions.php, but $language = 'English';  was already set, and I still had that problem.

So I used an even cruder method and copied the contents of MAMP\bin\mamp\translate\English.json into German.json. When that worked, I renamed the json file, just to see if it still worked, and it did ... :-)

But it's an awful method, and having that page synchronised by default with the language set during installation should be the professional way. I'll submit this as a request to MAMP.